# How can i control my clock speed using Racket?

Tags: racket

I tried to write a program that counting down from 10 to 0 using Racket.  It worked but the counting is going too fast, is there a way to implement a set time that count one second per turn?  I've been working on it but couldn't find anyway.  Thank for your time. Here's my code so far:

```
;; Functions:

;; countdown -> countdown
;; start the world with main at CTR-X CTR-Y 
;; 
  (define (main cd)
    (big-bang cd                              ; countdown
              (on-tick advance-countdown)     ; countdown -> countdown
              (to-draw render)                ; countdown -> Image
              (on-key handle-key)             ; countdown KeyEvent ->
                                                countdown
              (on-mouse handle-mouse)))       ; Integer Integer MouseEvent 
                                              ; -> countdown

;; countdown -> countdown
;; produce the next number by decrease by 1 from the previous number 
   (check-expect (advance-countdown 5) 4)
   (check-expect (advance-countdown 0) 0)

;(define (advance-countdown cd) 0)  ; stub
;;<use template from Countdown>
  (define (advance-countdown cd)
    (if (= cd 0)
        0
        (- cd 1)))

;; countdown -> Image
;; render ... 
  (check-expect (render 4) (place-image (text (number->string 4) TEXTSIZE 
                                         TEXT-COLOR) CTR-X CTR-Y MTS))
;(define (render cd) MTS) ; stub

  (define (render cd) 
    (place-image (text (number->string cd) TEXTSIZE TEXT-COLOR)
                 CTR-X
               CTR-Y
               MTS))

;; countdown KeyEvent -> countdown
;; reset countdown to 10
   (check-expect (handle-key 10 " ") 10)
   (check-expect (handle-key 10 "a") 10) 
;(define (handle-key cd ke) 0) ; stub

   (define (handle-key cd ke)
     (cond [(key=? ke " ") 10]
           [else cd]))
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a 'Timer'. Racket has a few different notions of timer built into it, and you can even make your own. But two of the more prominent built in ones are:

- [`timer%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/timer_.html?q=timer%25) - from the `racket/gui/base` library, and
- [`timer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/timer.html?q=timer#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fprivate%2Ftimer..rkt%29._timer%29%29) - from the web server library.

Or you could just make your own using [`alarm-evt`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/timer.html?q=timer#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fprivate%2Ftimer..rkt%29._timer%29%29) and [`sync`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sync.html?q=evt#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._sync%29%29). (You can also make your own timer from more 'low level' primitives, but I would not recommend doing so, as its easy to make subtle mistakes and get the wrong time.

Since it looks like you are already using a gui (although the `HTDP2` GUI rather than `racket/gui`), lets user `timer%`. Simply create a callback that decrements the timer, and stops when it reaches 0.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui/base)
(define count 10)
(displayln count)
(define the-timer
  (new timer% [notify-callback
                (lambda ()
                  (set! count (- count 1))
                  (displayln count)
                  (when (= count 0)
                    (send the-timer stop)))]
              [interval 1000]))
```

Now, when you run this program, it should count from 10 to 0 1 second at a time. We can test this out with the [`current-milliseconds`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html?q=current-milliseoncds#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-milliseconds%29%29) function. Simply grab the start time, the end time, and take the difference. When I ran this on my machine I got a total time of '10138' ms, or 10.138 seconds.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote in Racket but is there a reason not to use `sleep` from `racket/base`?

Comment: You can do it. And if you want to avoid using racket/gui/base that is one nice way to do it. (Although in that case I would still recommend `alarm-evt` and  and `sync`. The real gatcha is that after every time the thread wakes up, it must sample its current time to see how long it 'actually' slept, and set the next alarm accordingly. This is because sleep only guarantees that a thread will sleep 'at least' as long as you ask it to, but it can (and often will) sleep more than that.